# repaint() JPanel if previous repaint() complete

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I have a this loop in class `collection` which `repaint()` JPanel continiously

```
    while(loop) {
        imageicon = (ImageIcon) ois.readObject();
        image = imageicon.getImage();
        cjpanel.tempimage = image;
        cjpanel.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

and `cjpanel` extends JPanel where i have overridden `paintComponent()` and i am using `Double buffering`

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
tempimage.getScaledInstance(dim.width, dim.height, Image.SCALE_FAST);
bufferGraphics.clearRect(0,0,dim.width,dim.width);
bufferGraphics.drawImage(tempimage,0,0,dim.width,dim.height, null);
g.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,this);
}
```

my problem is `repaint` is always two frames behind while loop. i.e if `image 4` is in `while` loop then `paintComponent()` is drawing `image 2.

So how can i Speed up `repaint` or stop new `repaint` before previous `repaint` is done?

**UPDATE**

when I changed the size of image from ObjectInputStream it is working fine. I think it has to do something with image size..

Comment: Where is your `while` loop located?  Where is the code that uses `image`?  Also, you are calling `tempimage.getScaledInstance` but you're ignoring the returned scaled image.  Also, keeping the same `bufferGraphics` object "open" should work in theory, but has a bad code smell to it, in my opinion.  Finally, JPanel does its own double-buffering, so you probably should pass your image to a `drawImage` method which takes four int arguments, rather then scaling it yourself.

Comment: @VGR please see my updated question.. i am using `cjpanel` to display images

Comment: "*and i am using Double buffering*" Swing is already double buffering, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @user1803551 yes Swing is already double buffering..

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not be re-reading images within your while loop. Read the images in once and store them in a variable, likely a collection such as an ArrayList.
2. Store them as Images or Icons depending on how you are using them. No need to call getImage() on an Icon when you can store the images as Images.
3. Don't use a while loop but rather a Swing Timer so as not to run afoul of Swing threading rules.
4. You're asking for debugging help, essentially, "why isn't this code working as expected?" help, and so if general advice doesn't help, you really must strongly consider creating and posting the shortest code necessary for us to be able to compile, run and help identify your problem, a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check the link). Else, we're not going to be able to help well other than to give general advice, as I've done above. And I agree that what I'm requesting would not be an easy or quick thing to do as it would require quite a bit of effort on your part, but if you remain stuck and need a solution to this, it would be effort well spent. Up to you, and depends solely on your need.

Comment: `tempimage` in `paintComponent` is image so i have to getImage()

Comment: @reenleedr: You're asking for debugging help, essentially, "why isn't this code working as expected?" help, and so if general advice doesn't help, you really must create and post the shortest code necessary for us to be able to compile, run and help identify your problem. Else, we're not going to be able to help well other than to give general advice, as I've done above.

Comment: sir, i am trying to find shortest example but my application is too complicated..

Comment: @reenleedr: I agree that what I'm requesting would not be an easy or quick thing to do as it would require quite a bit of effort on your part, but if you remain stuck and need a solution to this, it would be effort well spent. Up to you, and depends solely on your need. Regardless, good luck!

Comment: @reenleedr: for an example of using a Swing Timer  and an ArrayList of images, please look at my code answer in [this recent program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33219497/522444). In it, I create an `ArrayList<Icon>` to hold ImageIcons of increasing sizes of an image. Then when the mouse hovers over the button a Swing Timer is triggered that swaps the icons in succession, showing a growing image. The reverse happens when the mouse leaves the button.

Answer (score 2):

The repaint manager can collapse sequential call to `repaint` so that if you paint one frame for each image some images might not show. You can use `paintImmediately` to force the repaint:

> Paints the specified region in this component and all of its descendants that overlap the region, immediately.
>
> It's rarely necessary to call this method. In most cases it's more efficient to call repaint, which defers the actual painting and can collapse redundant requests into a single paint call. This method is useful if one needs to update the display while the current event is being dispatched.

As for

> when I changed the size of image from ObjectInputStream it is working fine.

It might factor into the repaint manager's calculation of how / which repaint calls to collapse.

I suggest you try this method and see if it works, though it is more difficult to implement (read the API carefully).

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120528/repaint-in-a-loop) for refreshing my memory.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. I think that if this is the solution then this question should be marked as a duplicate of the one i linked.

Comment: Is `paintImmediately` called after `repaint()` or should it be manually called like OBJ.paintImmediately(rectangle r)

Comment: @reenleedr The latter (didn't test myself).

Comment: does `paintImmediately` calls `paintComponent`??

Comment: @reenleedr I think it calls `paint`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031653/how-does-jcomponent-paintimmediately-work-in-java-swing). Will have to look at the source code to know for sure.